# Is it possible to get a PyQt5 Application (On MacOS) to not accept activation/focus completely, but still be interactable?

Tags: python, macos, pyqt5, focus, active-window

I am currently trying to create a PyQt5 application that sends OSC messages to ETC's EOS lighting software. I have a single encoder wheel working to modify the pan values of a moving light. However, I don't want the PyQt5 application to be activated and take focus away from the EOS software. I want to be able to click and drag the encoder wheel I created and then immediately have EOS still active so I can use the keyboard shortcuts for recording commands, setting intensity or other values, etc. I am struggling to find a way to make the PyQt5 application not take focus/activation when clicking and dragging the Dial widget. I have looked everywhere I can find to try and solve this issue and I know about "setWindowsFlags" for PyQt5, but they don't accomplish what I am trying to solve. My best guess is that the windows flags are being set for the window and/or widgets, but not for the application as a whole. Is there a way to do this? Is there some other Python module out there that can help me accomplish this?

Here is a portion of the code I have for creating the dial widget

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

class Dial(QDial):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setNotchesVisible(False)
        self.setWrapping(True)
        self.setRange(0, 25)
        self.valueChanged.connect(self.emitValueChanged)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus)
    
    @property
    def dialVal(self):
        return self.value()

    def emitValueChanged(self, dialVal):
        print(self.value())

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags( Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_ShowWithoutActivating)
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        self.dial = Dial()
    
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.dial)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.dial)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen = MainWindow()
screen.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Try with the `Qt.BypassWindowManagerHint` flag. Also, your question really doesn't have anything to do with your final purpose (the OSC connection and the custom dial), so you should remove the description and code related to that. Just explain the actual problem, and add a basic QDial in the main window code.

Comment: I have tried BypassWindowManagerHint. Still doesn’t prevent activation. None of the Window Flags work for it.

Comment: Unfortunately, each OS/window manager has its own way of dealing with flags (in reality, it's the other way around, as Qt window flags are an abstraction that the platform plugin eventually applies to the underlying OS). Also, Apple OSs are known to break lots of established rules whenever they feel, including their own. The only thing I can suggest you is to create a test program that shows all possible window flags as check boxes in a window, and eventually applies them to a "test" window. But, be aware: considering Apple inconsistencies, it's not guaranteed to work under all circumstances.